# General unsupervised learning strategy when using convolutional autoencoder (CAE)

Tags: keras, unsupervised-learning, convolution, autoencoder

I am working on implementing an autoencoder for unsupervised learning, and I have some questions about the overall process. From what I was reading [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3464), @rjpg suggests the following general approach:

1. Slice the NN in half on the last encoder (before the decode starts)
2. Freeze the the weights of the encoders
3. Add or concat a new NN in front of the last encoding layer
4. (post) Train this concat NN with a softmax output layer to classify the digit

I haven't been able to find an example of this using Keras.  I have seen examples in R or H20, but the code is so encapsulated, it is difficult for me to implement a similar solution in Keras.  I have three questions related to how to implement this:

1. Does this strategy seem reasonable?
2. How to freeze the weights of the encoders in Keras?
3. What is meant by adding or concatting a new NN in front of the last encoding layer, or why is this needed?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question does not appear to be about unsupervised learning, but starts after the unsupervised part has finished, and is about how to re-use the unsupervised autoencoder as a component in a supervised learning problem. This is normal, especially if you want to predict something as opposed to compress or de-noise the data. But could you clarify is that your goal, to understand this re-use and predict digits on MNIST as a practice exercise in Keras?